# checking multiple elements in javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have an array 'type' with multiple elements.how to check two elements contains in 'type' array?
i have tried the below code

```
 var i, j;
                var type = [];
                for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                {
                    var filetype_value = parseInt((document.submission['select_type_' + i].value));
                    type.push(filetype_value);

                }
                function search(arg)
                {
                    for (j = 1; j <= count; j++)
                    {
                        if (type[j] === arg)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                            {
                            return false;
                            }
                    }

                }
                if(search(1) && search(2))
{
alert("Contains in array")
}
```

Comment: What is the count? where you define that?

Comment: you are pushing a string `'filetype_value'` not the variable `filetype_value`: `type.push(filetype_value);`

Comment: @AntoKing I think copy paste of code...

Comment: filetype_value is the dynamic values getting from html form.and count is the number of elements .that part is working fine.

Comment: i just need to know how to get an array contains multiple elements

Comment: no how filetype_value will wotk? because you used single codes like 'filetype_value' so it will become string not as varible anymore

Comment: why are you starting the for loop(in second function) with one? if you do so then the first value of array will not be compared.

Comment: yes u r ryt.i deleted that single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problems with your approach.

**1)** You are just checking if `type[1]===arg` it will return `true` otherwise it will return false. So it will just check for `type[1]`.

**2)** because `file_type` value is string so `filetype_value' === arg` is never going to be true.

**3)** In your loop `j=1` will never check for `first` element of array.

Try this

```
function search(arg){
var matched = false;
for (j = 0; j <= type.length; j++){
    if (type[j] == arg){
        matched = true;
        break;
    }
}
return matched;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems

1. You are pushing the string "filetype_value" onto your array and not the actual value so in your search function you are actually testing: `'filetype_value' === arg`
2. You are starting your loop using 1, array's start at an index of 0

change

```
type.push('filetype_value');
```

to

```
type.push(filetype_value);
```

change

```
for (j = 1; j <= count; j++)
```

to

```
for (j = 0; j <= count; j++)
```

Also instead of doing a loop you can use the array [**indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method to test if a value is in the array

```
function search(arg){
   return type.indexOf(arg) !== -1;
}
```